# .Net resource localisation in VS 2013 dosn't work for cultures other than default

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to create some resouce files for my application. But it dosn't work for other languages else than default one. f.e:

1. myResource.fr-FR.resx

   - myResource.fr-FR.Designer.cs

     - Nothing
2. myResource.de-DE.resx

   - myResource.de-DE.Designer.cs

     - Nothing
3. myResource.resx

   - myResource.Designer.cs

     - myResource
     - Methods and properties of myResource

i have followed [Resx Files In App_GlobalResources](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/15/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) steps. But it dosn't help me anyway. i don't know if i need to install some other plugins for VS 2013. Here are my settings for a resource file.

- custom tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
- namespace: Resources
- build action: Embeded Resource
- I am using VS 2013 under Window 10

i would be greatly appriciated for any hints or helps.

Comment: Have you tried to check during the execution whether the current `UICulture `is the one you expect to get? Perhaps it is always default.

Comment: i have excuted nothing. only i want to create on resource file. Right click of Project in project explorer-->insert new item-->Resource-->type the name of file like myResource.de-DE.resx or myResource.en-GB.resx then ok. then insert some resources, then compile my project or execute the custom tool --> i will get no result at the moment. but if try for the file name myResource.resx, i'll get some localisation results.